# Ask for an example code for parsing xml and get attributes by using GData API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, gdata-api

When i use GData API in my app for parsing xml,how could i get attributes and it's value?
Wanted a piece of example code.Thanks a lot.
xml:

```
   <playurls><url islive="0" type="3" bit_stream="1">http://vods.netitv.com//dy2/2010/02/08/cf584b76-3579-4b75-a0c8-f7a473d79f8c.mp4
    </url><url islive="0" type="3" bit_stream="2">http://vods.netitv.com//dy/2010/02/08/965bbc65-8ec0-4c50-98ae-c69a831926cc.mp4
    </url><url islive="0" type="2" bit_stream="1">http://vods.netitv.com//dy2/2010/02/08/cf584b76-3579-4b75-a0c8-f7a473d79f8c.mp4
    </url><url islive="0" type="2" bit_stream="2">http://vods.netitv.com//dy/2010/02/08/965bbc65-8ec0-4c50-98ae-c69a831926cc.mp4
    </url></playurls>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 NSInteger type=[[(GDataXMLNode *)[[urls objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"type"] stringValue] intValue];
 NSInteger bit_stream=[[(GDataXMLNode *)[[urls objectAtIndex:i]attributeForName:@"bit_stream"] stringValue] intValue];
```

Comment: I got it，It must be  like this

Answer (score 0):

Google have provided quite a lot of sample code that shows how to use their API. Depending of which protocol you use, you should be able to get the samples from the [API Directory](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html).

Comment: I guess these help some but am sure there are many like me that find examples like these bloated with so much content it proves near impossible for a less experienced coder to get to grips with.  I dont see why those at google (other API suppliers too) dont offer more clear clean basic examples?  Apple too are guilty of this.