# Offline map from sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my application i have a MkMapview and now it shows current location. i have to bookmark some other locations and show that locations even if there is no Wi-Fi connection. How to bookmark that locations and how to display the offline maps? how to save map to cache? is it possible? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no public available API for caching the map images used by MKMapView. You might also be in violation of Googles terms and conditions by doing this.

However, Google have provided a [static map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) where you can grab a static portion of a map as an image file and possible cache this for later display. But again, check Google's T&C.

There are a number of other [map services](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) available through the [GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html), but they are somewhat more complex to use. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028020/ask-for-an-example-code-for-parsing-xml-and-get-attributes-by-using-gdata-api/3028144), shows a few hints on how to use these API's.