# Get XML response value with GDataXML

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing, response, gdata-api

after a HTTP Post I retrieve an xml response like the following:

```
<result value="OK">
    <user id="1">
            <name>admin</name>
            <rank>0</rank>
            <picture_count>0</picture_count>
            <comment_count>0</comment_count>
            <has_profile>1</has_profile>
    </user>
</result>
```

I'd like to extract the user ID, but I don't know how to do this.
I tried with `GDataXML` Parser, because this is already integrated in my project, but
I don't know how to get a value inside a html tag.

I hope you can help me. If there is no solution with `XMLParser`, would you recommend regular expressions? In this case, I would appreciate a solution for the regex expression, I'm not very good at this :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `attributeForName` for user tag element. For more information see this [stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028020/ask-for-an-example-code-for-parsing-xml-and-get-attributes-by-using-gdata-api)

Comment: Thanks, but if i use `GDataXMLElement *elem = doc.rootElement;
    NSString *userID = [[elem attributeForName:@"user id"]stringValue];  ` this returns null.

Comment: `attributeForName:@"id"` is correct. The attribute is `id` and not `user id`. Hope it helps.

Comment: `NSString *userID = [[elem attributeForName:@"id"]stringValue];`is still null. I also tried it with @"value" and this returns OK ... don't know why @"id" won't work. Do i have to work with `GDataXMLNode`? But i have no idea how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code I use to retrieve the user attribute. It works.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"xml"];

NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSError *error;
GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData 
                                                           options:0 error:&error];

NSArray *userElements = [doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"user"];

for (GDataXMLElement *userEl in userElements) {

    // Attribute
    NSString *attribute = [(GDataXMLElement *) [userEl attributeForName:@"id"] stringValue];        
    NSLog(@"attribute for user is %@", attribute);

    // Name
    NSArray *names = [userEl elementsForName:@"name"];
    if (names.count > 0) {
        GDataXMLElement *name = (GDataXMLElement *) [names objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"name for user is %@", name.stringValue);
    }

    // Rank
    NSArray *ranks = [userEl elementsForName:@"rank"];
    if (ranks.count > 0) {
        GDataXMLElement *rank = (GDataXMLElement *) [ranks objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"rank for user is %@", rank.stringValue);
    }

    // Do the same for other tags...     
}

[doc release];
[xmlData release];
```

The file test.xml is the same that you retrieve from the xml response. So you need to change the second line of this snippet of code. Maybe you can call `initWithData` method of class `NSData`.

You can put this code where you want. Maybe you can create an other class that works as a centralized parser. Hope it helps

**EDIT**

Put these two lines before for instruction.

```
NSString *valAttribute = [(GDataXMLElement *) [doc.rootElement attributeForName:@"value"] stringValue];        
NSLog(@"value attribute for result is %@", valAttribute);
```

The explanation is quite simple. With `doc.rootElement` you retrieve the entire xml document, from `<result>` to `</result>`

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't build this user array with these single user elements. This code works like a charm.

Comment: Little question afterwards: I'm trying to get the result value, with building the array `NSArray *resultElements = [doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"result"];` and then the same like get ´attributeForName@"value"` but the array is null.

Comment: Ok, @flexaddicted, but how to extract `Array`. I have array inside element and I don't know how to extract it.